_tkinter.TclError when trying to import FreeSimpleGUI and running it in PyCharm
I am trying to create a desktop GUI by importing FreeSimpleGUI by using the code below:
import FreeSimpleGUI
That code produced the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tleak\PythonProjects\todo_app\gui.py", line 2, in <module>
    import FreeSimpleGUI
  File "C:\Users\tleak\PythonProjects\todo_app\venv\bin\python\Lib\site-packages\FreeSimpleGUI\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .FreeSimpleGUI import *
  File "C:\Users\tleak\PythonProjects\todo_app\venv\bin\python\Lib\site-packages\FreeSimpleGUI\FreeSimpleGUI.py", line 45, in <module>
    tclversion_detailed = tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\tleak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in Tcl
    return Tk(screenName, baseName, className, useTk)
  File "C:\Users\tleak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2459, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Users/tleak/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/tleak/PythonProjects/todo_app/venv/bin/python/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/tleak/PythonProjects/todo_app/venv/bin/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/tleak/PythonProjects/todo_app/venv/bin/python/library C:/Users/tleak/PythonProjects/todo_app/venv/bin/library C:/Users/tleak/PythonProjects/todo_app/venv/bin/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/tleak/PythonProjects/todo_app/venv/tcl8.6.14/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

I expected the code to import FreeSimpleGUI successfully. I have un-installed everything attributed to Python and reinstalled to cancel out having too many Python installations. How can I solve this error code and successfully import FreeSimpleGUI to continue on with my project?

This is a bug in Python v3.13. For now, use Python version 3.12 or earlier.

Try this: py -3.13 -m pip install FreeSimpleGUI --upgrade  It will dowmloading under Python 3.13. If you persist, then update Python 3.14.0a1

In the program/script you are writing, you need to import the os module and then enter two path variables as follows:
Note: Look for the tcl and tk libraries in your python313 folder, and copy the relevant path. For me it was:
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\tcl\tk8.6'


Get back to me if it doesn't work.

Copying tcl and tk libraries in my python3.13 folder didn't work for me. I downloaded Matplotlib and I can run command:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

without any problem, however using any other command, such as:
print(plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,4,6]))

doesn't work and I get a very long error.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
